# Buy a small amount of Ethereum

Tags: exchanges

I'm new in Ethereum, and I would like to buy a very smart amount of Ethereum.

I want to learn more about ETH, and at the moment I would like to invest $10 or $15.

Do you know any website where I can buy this small amount? I already have a wallet.

Thank you.

Comment: I think's this question is already answered but check some exchange like coinbase

Comment: You will have to look for an exchange in your country that accept payments in fiat or the payment method of your choice. Other options is ask a seller in localbitcoins or localethereum.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your country, but Coinbase is one of the largest. You can buy there, and then send it to your wallet's address, though it will take some time to get verified.

Comment: What wallet do you refer here? Does someone needs to create a wallet first before purchasing Ethereum?

Comment: The question asker mentions that they already have a wallet. You don't need a wallet to purchase Ethereum from an exchange, however it's recommended so that you have complete control over your assets.

Comment: Sending to wallet might be costly, depending on how Coinbase make your transaction. Since it's very few amount you can keep on you coinbase account

Answer (score 0):

Since you've asked: https://transak.com/

I was testing the other day for small amounts, I think the minimum was £20, now the minimum seems £10?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can buy it on Binance or else do P2P transfer .